# General formula for number of strings created from $n$ letters, where $m$ are identical and the rest are distinct.

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

The problem:

Given $n$ letters, of which $m$ are identical and the rest are distinct, find a formula for the number of strings which can be made.

Tests:

Ex 1. n = 3, m = 0: DOG: { , D, O, G, DO, DG, OD, OG, GD, GO, DOG, DGO, ODG, OGD, GOD, GDO} = 16 strings where there are 1 len(0), 3 len(1), 6 len(2), and 6 len(3).

Ex 2. n = 3, m = 2: HII: { , H, I, II, HI, IH, HII, IIH, IHI} (the I's are indistinguishable) = 9 strings where there are 1 len(0), 2 len(1), 3 len(2), and 3 len(3).

I am trying to arrive at a general formula but it difficult to grasp the relation. I understand that the ways to permute $n$ distinct letters is just $n!$ but don't know how to extend my understanding of letters being repeated from a case by case basis to a general formula.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: What if you "divide-and-conquer" by considering first those strings of size $k$, for each $k \in \{1, 2, ..., n\}$? Given $k$, you then need to choose how many of the identical letter you will include, and choose where to put those in the $k$ possible locations.

Answer (score 1):

It has been some time, and I only saw this after going through my previous questions, but I figured out the answer to this question awhile back.

To reiterate, we are given $n$ letters, of which $m$ are identical and the rest distinct, and want to find a formula for the number of strings which can be made from them.

We have that the number of strings is equal to

$$\sum_{k\geq 0} \sum_{j=0}^m \binom{k}{j}\binom{n-m}{k-j}(k-j)!$$

This can be interpreted as first choosing the places in the string for the copies of repeated letters, then choosing the rest of the letters, and then finally ordering them.

Answer (score 0):

If all letters are different, you get $n!$ ways to arrange them. If now $m$ are different, and $n - m$ are the same,
you have $n!$, but by a factor $(n - m)!$ too large (consider you have $n - m$ letters $a_1, \dotsc, a_{n - m}$ and then $b, c, \dotsc$, arranging those gives $n!$ possibilities; if you "turn off" the subindices, collections of $(n - m)!$ collapse into strings of just $a, b, \dotsc$).

Check out [The Tao of BOOKKEEPER](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.042/past-devel/spring06/solutions/cp9fsol.pdf) for enlightenment.